# Image getting deleted from a file path

Tags: php

I have a dashboard where users can login and upload a profile picture of themselves which saves to their profile. This moves the image to the correct folder and also correctly inserts it into the db.

This has been working fine up until recently when I noticed the image disappeared. Within the inspect console I noticed I was getting a `404 not found` error on the image, so I checked inside the file path and the image was no longer in there (hence the 404). There is no script at all for the user to delete an image, only to upload.

**profile.php:**

```
<p><b>Profile Picture: </b>
<?php 
    $picture = $row['imagePath'];
    if (empty($picture)){
        echo "<img src='profiles/no-image.png' width='100' height='100' >";
    } else {
        echo "<img src='profiles/".$row['imagePath']."' width='100' height='100' >";    
    };
?>
<form action="scripts/edit-picture.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image"/>
    <input type="submit" name="edit-picture" value="Upload"/>
</p>
</form>
```

**script for edit-image.php**

```
<?php
    require 'db.php';
    session_start();
    $uploadDir = '../profiles/';

    // if edit-picture has been clicked on, run this if statement
    if (isset($_POST['edit-picture'])) {


        $studentID = $_SESSION['studentID'];

        // Creating 4 different variables using the $_FILES global variable to get data about the image that
        // you can view data about a file by doing: print_r($image);         
        $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $tmpName = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
        $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

        $filePath = $uploadDir.$fileName;
        // The below doesn't work as it assigns different value to folder and in db for image name
        // $filePath = md5($file_name . microtime()) . substr($fileName , -5, 5);

        $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);
        if (!$result) {
            header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileRelocate");
            exit;
        }
        // Checking file size - working
        else if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 5000000) {
            header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileSizeError");
            exit();
        }
        // Check if file name already exists in db - not working
        else if (file_exists($result)) {
            header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileNameExists");
            exit();
        }
        // Allow certain file formats - not working
        else if($result != "jpg" && $result != "png" && $result != "jpeg") {
            header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileTypeError");
            exit();
        }

        // This is to show any errors that may occur if the connection fails, this helps with error checking.
        else if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
              printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare ("INSERT INTO `profileImage` (`imagePath`, `studentID`) 
            VALUES ( ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `imagePath` = VALUES (`imagePath`) ");
            $stmt->bind_param("si", $fileName, $studentID); 
            $stmt->execute() or die("Failed to insert image into the database");

            header("Location: ../profile.php?img=successImageUploaded");
            exit();
        }
    }     
?>
```

**My folder structure:**

```
profiles
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
profile.php
scripts
    edit-image.php
```

Has anyone ever come across an image actually disappearing from a folder after it being moved in there via `move_uploaded_file` as ANY help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: an image can't disappear from a filesystem, I doubt you will receive any feedback for your issue. However, do you have another script which makes it possible for the user to remove his picture ? If so, maybe there's a mistake in there and files which shouldn't be deleted are removed. That's an idea

Comment: Hi @Pierre I know, I'm just baffled, no there is not even a script for them to delete their image.

Comment: Are you sure the image is really uploaded and moved ? HAve you been able to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: @Pierre yes, the image gets moved into the folder path which is the `$uploadDir = '../profiles/';` and also appears as a new row in the table `profileImage`

Comment: then if are sure the image is uploaded (checked with FTP explorer), the issue is not in the code ; maybe your host had a big issue with its servers and had to restore your files to a previous date

Comment: Ah I think I've possibly found the issue, I code with the IDE of Visual Studio Code, which is linked to GitHub, the image saves into my staged changes, but when I delete from the staged changes in VS Code, that also actually deletes the image from the folder. weird!!

Comment: `$result != "jpg"` -  $result - this appear as boolean, result from move_uploaded_file. If you want check that file is image use for example function `getimagesize` and check `mime` value.

Comment: and another mistake `file_exists($result)` (line 32) $result is boolean, you must check that file exists before you move it.

Comment: @PavelMusil I see, I was wondering why those two checks weren't producing anything at all, would this check be as simple as if `$result == true` then move, or am i on the wrong lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve conditions for image upload and don't overwrite existing image files:

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
session_start();
$uploadDir = '../profiles/';

// if edit-picture has been clicked on, run this if statement
if (isset($_POST[ 'edit-picture' ])) {


    $studentID = $_SESSION[ 'studentID' ];

    // Creating 4 different variables using the $_FILES global variable to get data about the image that
    // you can view data about a file by doing: print_r($image);
    $fileName = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'name' ];
    $tmpName = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'tmp_name' ];
    $fileSize = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'size' ];
    $fileType = $_FILES[ 'image' ][ 'type' ];

    $filePath = $uploadDir . $fileName;
    // The below doesn't work as it assigns different value to folder and in db for image name
    // $filePath = md5($file_name . microtime()) . substr($fileName , -5, 5);

    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileNameExists");
        exit();

    } // Checking file size - working
    else if ($_FILES[ "image" ][ "size" ] > 5000000) {
        header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileSizeError");
        exit();
    }
    $info = getimagesize($tmpName);
    // empty $info - not known image
    if (empty($info)) {
        header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileTypeError");
        exit();
    } // This is to show any errors that may occur if the connection fails, this helps with error checking.

    $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $filePath);

    if (!$result) {
        header("Location: ../profile.php?img=errorFileRelocate");
        exit;
    }
    else if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    } else {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `profileImage` (`imagePath`, `studentID`)
            VALUES ( ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `imagePath` = VALUES (`imagePath`) ");
        $stmt->bind_param("si", $fileName, $studentID);
        $stmt->execute() or die("Failed to insert image into the database");

        header("Location: ../profile.php?img=successImageUploaded");
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I did try this, however I get the message of "FileNameExists" when I'm just trying to upload a different photo (even though the file name of the new image I'm trying to upload is NOT the same), perhaps the order of the `else if` is in the wrong place, not sure....